# Equals with multiple values Java

Tags: java, equals

I've made a Java class in which I simulate a Polynome (it contains an `ArrayList<Pairs>`, each pair has its own coefficient and exponent). But now I like to compare two Polynome's with the `equals()` method (with an `Object`).

I know I can't say that this == that because this will only compare the Polynome references. SO now I wondered if there's an easy way to compare both Polynome's values, or do I just have to check the first Pair of the first Polynome to the first Pair of the second Polynome etc.?

Comment: Yes compare all relevant fields. Also implement hashCode()

Comment: The equals() method is supposed to implement your definition of equality. If your definition of equality is that 2 polynomials are equal when their respective pairs are equal, then obviously, that should be the implementation of the equals method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override the `equals()` method of your `Pair` class to return true if and only if both the coefficient and the exponent are equal.

You should also override the `hashCode()` method if you override `equals()`. Although strictly speaking this isn't mandatory while you're using `ArrayList`s, it is good practice to always override `equals()` and `hashCode()` together.

Also note that because you're using a `List`, where the order of elements matters, x<sup>3</sup>+2x-1 won't be equal to 2x-1+x<sup>3</sup>, which is probably not what you want to see. You should store your `Pair` objects in a `Set` instead, as their `equals()` doesn't rely on the order in which you added the elements to them.

Answer (score 1):

You have to override equals and check each and every `Monomial` in the `Polynomial` collection.

Hint: I'd have two classes - `Monomial`, with its own equals and hashCode, and a separate `Polynomial`, which would have a `Set` of `Monomials` and its own equals and hashCode.